Using difference quotients to find the surface area of a parametric surface
I am reading Stewart’s book on multivariable calculus to brush up before reading about electrodynamics and I encountered the following attempt to define the surface area of a parametric surface, which I find confusing.
(For reference this is on page 1128-1129 of this book.)
Let $\mathbf{r}(u,v) = x(u,v)\mathbf{i} + y(u,v)\mathbf{j} + z(u,v)\mathbf{k}$ be a vector valued function defined on the parameter region $D$ in the $uv$ plane and which maps to a surface $S$ in $\mathbb{R^3}$. For simplicity’s sake, we consider a surface where $D$ forms a rectangle. Divide $D$ into subrectangles $R_{ij}$ and let the bottom left point of $R_{ij}$ be $(u_i^*,v_j^*)$. Each $R_{ij}$ gets mapped to a patch on $S$; call that patch $S_{ij}$ and let its bottom left point be $P_{ij}$, which has position vector $\mathbf{r}(u_i^*,v_j^*)$.
Now, Stewart’s next step is to approximate the edges of each patch $S_{ij}$ using vectors and then approximate its area using the cross product of the parallelogram formed by those vectors. This general idea makes sense to me, but the way in which he executes it does not. Specifically, he takes the tangent vectors at $P_{ij}$, given by $\mathbf{r}_u^*$ and $\mathbf{r}_v^*$, respectively the partial derivative of $\mathbf{r}$
with respect to $u$ at $P_{ij}$ and the partial derivative of $\mathbf{r}$ with respect to $v$ at $P_{ij}$ - and then multiplies them by $\Delta u$ and $\Delta v$, respectively, to approximate the sides as $\Delta u \mathbf{r}_u^*$ and $\Delta v \mathbf{r}_v^*$. This part is what doesn’t make sense to me. Stewart calls $\Delta u$ and $\Delta v$ “difference quotients” but I am not sure what that means in this context -  I cannot find this phrase anywhere else in the book and after looking up the definition I’m not sure how to apply it in this scenario, i.e I cannot see why scaling the tangent vectors by these difference quotients must give the approximate side lengths of $S_{ij}$.

Stewart does not call $\Delta u$ and $\Delta v$ "difference quotients". He says that partial derivatives can be approximated by difference quotients. This fact is now known since the days of Newton and Leibniz if not decades earlier.

$\Delta u$ is not the difference quotient; the difference quotient is $\frac{r(u_i^* + \Delta u,v_j^*) - r(u_i^*,v_j^*)}{\Delta u}$. Then since
$\frac{r(u_i^* + \Delta u,v_j^*) - r(u_i^*,v_j^*)}{\Delta u} \approx \mathbf{r}_u^*$, $\Delta u \mathbf{r}_u^*$ gives the vector that approximates the bottom of the patch, i.e the vector from the point $P_{ij}$ to the point $P_{i+1j}$.
